# An sql query to get small qty value from a list of products

Tags: mysql

I have a product table. look like this.

I want my output to be like the following.
means only single product  row where the qty would be the small

```
       id     Product     Qty    Rate 
        1     AAAA       200     100 
        1     AAAA       400     200 
        1     AAAA       800     400 
        2     BBBB       500     150 
        2     BBBB      1000     300
```

I need the output like this. Means only the small qty of a product to display

```
        id     Product     Qty    Rate 
        1     AAAA       200     100 
        2     BBBB       500     150
```

I wrote this query but can it be a single query with one while loop.

```
$query="SELECT  id FROM hproducts where category='".$category."'group by  id order by qty";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($notic = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {       
    $query2="SELECT  id,productname,rate,qty,image FROM hproducts where id='".$noti['id']."'group by  id,productname,rate,qty,image order by qty limit 1";
    $result2=mysql_query($query2);
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
     ...
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.

```
$query = "
  select
    p1.id, p1.rate, p1.qty, p1.image
  from
    hproducts p1
    inner join (
      select id, min(qty) as qty from hproducts ps group by ps.id
    ) p2 on p2.id = p1.id and p2.qty = p1.qty
  where p1.category = '$category'";
```

The subselect gets the lowest quantity per product, which is then joined (and thereby used as a filter) for hproduct (alias p1).